# ¿Cómo estructurar una GUI (tkinter) para que tenga en archivos separados la App principal y los componentes secundarios?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

**¡Hola comunidad!**

Estoy en desarrollo de una app que contiene muchas líneas de código. Aprovechando las ventajas que brinda *Python* deseo separar el código en diversos archivos o módulos que interactúen entre sí.

El objetivo es crear un archivo llamado `App.pyw` donde se almacenará la raíz de la interfaz gráfica (`self.root = tk.Tk()`) y otro(s) donde se encuentren los widgets a los que denomino secundarios (ej: `tk.Menu` ó `tk.Toplevel`).

Sucede que, en algunos casos, uno de los módulos secundarios necesita utilizar algún componente del archivo principal (`App.pyw`) para realizar una determinada tarea y, en mi caso, al ser llamados con algún método no llegan a ejecutarse. A continuación muestro un ejemplo:

Como dije anteriormente, tenemos un archivo llamado `App.pyw`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

from menu_modulo import *  # Módulo que contiene un widget de tipo tk.Menu

class mi_app():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        mi_menu = un_menu(self)
        self.root.config(menu=mi_menu)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = mi_app()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

...y otro archivo que funciona como módulo de `'App.pyw'`, llamado `menu_modulo.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class un_menu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.file = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.file.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.exit)

        self.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=self.file)

    def exit(self):
        valor = messagebox.askquestion('Salir', '¿Estás seguro de querer salir?')
        if valor == 'yes':
            self.root.destroy()
```

Al ejecutar el programa, aparentemente, todo marcha bien, salvo cuando el usuario selecciona la pestaña "Archivo" y elige la opción de "Salir"; puesto que a pesar de confirmar su solicitud, el programa no se cierra.

La intérprete de *Python* muestra el mensaje:

```
AttributeError: 'un_menu' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Supongamos que el menú también tuviese una opción de, por ejemplo, redimensionar el tamaño de la ventana, también necesitaría modificar a `self.root`, e intuyo que se presentaría el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente pasa al constructor del widget hijo las referencias que necesites, en este caso no necesitas pasar nada, con `parent` tenemos, pero debes tener en cuenta algunas cosas:

- Como padre del widget hijo (el menú en este caso), no le puedes pasar `self`. Ten en cuenta que `self` en este caso es una referencia a la instancia de `mi_app`, que no es un widget de tkinter y por tanto no es un padre válido, debes pasar `self.root` al inicializador.
- Pasa **siempre** al inicializador de la clase de la que heredes la referencia al padre, es decir, en vez de:

  ```
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
  super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
  ```
- En el menú, para acceder a la referencia del padre debes usar `self.master`, no `self.root`. `self.root` es un atributo de instancia de tu clase `mi_app`, pero no de `un_menu`.

**`app.py`**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

from menu_modulo import UnMenu


class MiApp():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        mi_menu = UnMenu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=mi_menu)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = MiApp()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

**`menu_modulo.py`**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class UnMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.file = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.file.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.exit)

        self.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=self.file)

    def exit(self):
        valor = messagebox.askquestion('Salir', '¿Estás seguro de querer salir?')
        if valor == 'yes':
            self.master.destroy()
```

Si se diera el caso de que un widget necesitara una referencia a la instancia de `MiApp` y no solo a su atributo `root`, siempre puedes pasar la referencia al inicializador:

**`app.py`**

```
class MiApp():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        mi_menu = UnMenu(self.root, app=self)
```

**`menu_modulo.py`**

```
class UnMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, app=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.app = app

    # Usa self.app como quieras, por ejemplo self.app.root.destroy()
```

Un par de observaciones sobre le código que no son errores, pero que deberías considerar:

- Te recomiendo encarecidamente que sigas las convenciones de estilo y que nombres siempre los módulos, funciones, métodos y variables con minúsculas y `_` como separador y reserves el CamelCase para los nombres de clases y TODO_EN_MAYUSCULAS para las "constantes". Nada te obliga a ello, insisto, pero ayuda mucho a otros desarrolladores a leer el código e identificar que es una clase y que no solo con ver el nombre.
- Además, considera evitar en lo posible el uso del star/wildcard para importar (`from modulo import *`). Aunque en éste caso el módulo es creado por ti y por tanto se supone que es seguro importarlo sin que exista solapamientos indebidos de namespaces, de nuevo tenemos un problema de legibilidad.

  Cuando el código es más extenso y se realizan varios imports de éste tipo, llega un momento que es imposible determinar de dónde sale cada nombre. Con ello obligas a otros desarrolladores (y a veces a uno mismo) a ir viendo módulo por módulo a ver si encuentran la clase o variable o a usar técnicas de introspección.

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  from modulo1 import *
  from modulo2 import *
  from modulo3 import *

  n = PI * 13
  bar = Bar(n)
  foo = Foo(E)
  ```

  ¿De dónde vienen `Bar`,`Foo`, `PI` y `E`?.

  Todo queda más claro si haces:

  ```
  from modulo1 import Foo
  from modulo2 import Bar
  from modulo3 import PI, E

  n = PI * 13
  bar = Bar(n)
  foo = Foo(E)
  ```

  o:

  ```
  import modulo1
  import modulo2
  import modulo3

  n = modulo3.PI * 13
  bar = modulo2.Bar(n)
  foo = modulo1.Foo(modulo3.E)
  ```

  o:

  ```
  import modulo1 as mod1
  import modulo2 as mod2
  import modulo3 as mod3

  n = mod3.PI * 13
  bar = mod2.Bar(n)
  foo = mod1.Foo(mod3.E)
  ```