# ¿Cómo usar el método "bind" de tkinter cuando se está implementando POO?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

Estuve practicando en cómo organizar una GUI en la que el código estuviera separado en diversos módulos.
De esta forma, creé en un mismo directorio los siguientes archivos:

- **`app.pyw`**: El módulo principal de la aplicación.
- **`notebook_app.py`**: Para darle la estructura del widget tk.Notebook a la aplicación.
- **`menu_app.py`**: Para agregar un widget de tipo tk.Menu a la aplicación.
- **`sumar_app.py`**: Conjunto de instrucciones para realizar una determinada operación (suma).
- **`restar_app.py`**: Conjunto de instrucciones para realizar una determinada operación (restar).
- **`__init__.py`**: Para darle comportamiento de paquete al directorio.

Cada uno de estos módulos tienen clases que interactúan entre sí, con el objeto de facilitar la lectura y edición por parte de eventuales colaboradores. De esta manera, el código de cada uno es:

**`app.pyw`**:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Módulos propios de la App que deberán ser importados
import notebook_app as nbapp
import menu_app as menapp
import sumar_app as sumapp
import restar_app as restapp

class FrameInicialApp(tk.Frame):
    '''
    Esta clase tiene la finalidad de ser el contenedor de la ventana inicial
    de app.pyw. Contendrá los primeros widgets percibidos por el usuario.
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Label(self, text='BIENVENIDO A SU PROGRAMA'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.__sumar_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Crear pestaña de sumar',
            command=self.tab_sumar)
        self.__sumar_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')

        self.__restar_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Crear pestaña de restar',
            command=self.tab_restar)
        self.__restar_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')

    def tab_sumar(self):
        self.event_generate('<<NuevaPestañaSumar>>')

    def tab_restar(self):
        self.event_generate('<<NuevaPestañaRestar>>')

class App:
    '''
    Clase principal de la GUI. Ella deberá poder crear y manipular al resto de 
    clases pertenecientes a los módulos menu_app.py, notebook_app.py,
    sumar_app.py y restar_app.py
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.__menu = menapp.MenuApp(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.__menu)

        self.__nb = nbapp.NotebookApp(self.root)

        self.__fm = FrameInicialApp(self.__nb)
        self.__fm.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.__fm.bind('<<NuevaPestañaSumar>>', self.crear_tab_sumar)
        self.__fm.bind('<<NuevaPestañaRestar>>', self.crear_tab_restar)

        self.__nb.add(self.__fm, text='INICIO')
        self.__nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def crear_tab_sumar(self, event):
        self.sumar_pestaña = sumapp.SumarApp(self.__nb)
        self.__nb.add(self.sumar_pestaña, text='SUMAR')
        self.__nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.__nb.select(self.sumar_pestaña)

    def crear_tab_restar(self, event):
        self.restar_pestaña = restapp.RestarApp(self.__nb)
        self.__nb.add(self.restar_pestaña, text='RESTAR')
        self.__nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.__nb.select(self.restar_pestaña)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

**`notebook_app.py`:**

```
from tkinter import ttk

class NotebookApp(ttk.Notebook):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Se muestra de la forma más básica. Está clase
        # puede personalizarse a gusto.
```

**`menu_app.py`:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import sumar_app as sumapp
import restar_app as restapp

class MenuApp(tk.Menu):
    '''
    Esta clase fue creada con la finalidad de implementarse como el menú principal
    de la aplicación llamada app.pyw
    
    Debe tener la potestad de modificar componentes de la app principal, así como de
    manipular instrucciones para las pestañas "sumar" y "restar".
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.archivo = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.archivo.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.salir)

        self.vista = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.vista.add_command(label='Modo ventana', command=self.modo_ventana)
        self.vista.add_command(label='Modo pantalla completa',
            command=self.modo_pantalla_completa)

        self.preferencias = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.preferencias.add_command(label='Modo oscuro', command=None)
        self.preferencias.add_command(label='Modo claro', command=None)

        self.ayuda = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.ayuda.add_command(label='Documentación', command=self.documentacion)
        self.ayuda.add_command(label='Acerca de...', command=self.acerca_de)

        self.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=self.archivo)
        self.add_cascade(label='Vista', menu=self.vista)
        self.add_cascade(label='Preferencias', menu=self.preferencias)
        self.add_cascade(label='Ayuda', menu=self.ayuda)

        comandos_sumar = sumapp.SumarApp(self)
        comandos_sumar.bind('<<GuardarResultado>>', self.guardar_resultado_suma)

        comandos_restar = restapp.RestarApp(self)
        comandos_restar.bind('<<GuardarResultado>>', self.guardar_resultado_resta)


    def salir(self):
        valor = messagebox.askquestion('Salida del progama', '¿Estás segur@ de querer salir?')
        if valor == 'yes':
            self.master.destroy()

    def modo_ventana(self):
        self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

    def modo_pantalla_completa(self):
        self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    def documentacion(self):
        messagebox.showinfo('Documentación', 'Visite Python.org')

    def acerca_de(self):
        messagebox.showinfo('Acerca de...', 'Esta es solo una GUI de muestra.')

    def guardar_resultado_suma(self, event):
        self.archivo.add_command(label='Guardar', command=None)

    def guardar_resultado_resta(self, event):
        self.archivo.add_command(label='Guardar', command=None)
```

**`sumar_app.py`:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import menu_app as menapp

class SumarApp(tk.Frame):
    '''
    Esta clase deberá tener un conjunto de instrucciones para
    que el usuario pueda realizar dicha operación básica.

    En algunos casos, el módulo menu_app.py deberá poder
    manipular su información. Por ejemplo, para guardar algún 
    resultado hallado dentro de esta clase.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.__valor_1 = tk.DoubleVar(self)
        self.__valor_2 = tk.DoubleVar(self)
        self.__resultado = tk.DoubleVar(self)

        tk.Label(self, text='Aquí podrá realizar sumas'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 1:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=0,  columnspan=None, sticky='w')

        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 2:'
            ).grid(row=2, column=0,  columnspan=None, sticky='w')

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__valor_1).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__valor_2).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='e')

        tk.Button(self, text='¡Sumar!', command=self.sumar).grid(row=3, column=0)

    def sumar(self):
        '''
        Este método intenterá realizar la suma algebraíca entre los dos (2) valores 
        ingresados en el inicializador de la clase.
        '''
        while True:
            try:
                self.__resultado.set(self.__valor_1.get()+self.__valor_2.get())
                
                tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__resultado,
                    state='readonly').grid(row=4, column=0)
                self.event_generate('<<GuardarResultado>>')
                break
            
            except:
                messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Has colocado mal un valor.')
                break
```

**`restar_app.py`:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class RestarApp(tk.Frame):
    '''
    Esta clase deberá tener un conjunto de instrucciones para
    que el usuario pueda realizar dicha operación básica.

    En algunos casos, el módulo menu_app.py deberá poder
    manipular su información. Por ejemplo, para guardar algún 
    resultado hallado dentro de esta clase.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.__valor_1 = tk.DoubleVar(self)
        self.__valor_2 = tk.DoubleVar(self)
        self.__resultado = tk.DoubleVar(self)

        tk.Label(self, text='Aquí podrá realizar restas'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 1:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=0,  columnspan=None, sticky='w')

        tk.Label(self, text='Valor 2:'
            ).grid(row=2, column=0,  columnspan=None, sticky='w')

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__valor_1).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__valor_2).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='e')

        tk.Button(self, text='¡Restar!', command=self.restar).grid(row=3, column=0)

    def restar(self):
        '''
        Este método intenterá realizar la resta algebraíca entre los dos (2) valores 
        ingresados en el inicializador de la clase.
        '''
        while True:
            try:
                self.__resultado.set(self.__valor_1.get()-self.__valor_2.get())
                
                tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.__resultado,
                    state='readonly').grid(row=4, column=0)
                self.event_generate('<<GuardarResultado>>')
                break
            
            except:
                messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Has colocado mal un valor.')
                break
```

En un principio, al ejecutar el programa todo parece marchar bien. Se logra el objetivo de dividir el código en diversos módulos. ¿Dónde surge el problema?:

El menú de la aplicación, en su estado inicial, se presentan ciertos comandos elementales, como los son los típicos "Salir" o "Acerca de...". Luego, cuando el usuario crea una pestaña adicional y realiza una determinada operación, al finalizarla deberían aparecer nuevos comandos en el menú de la app, como lo son el "Volver atrás", "Exportar" "Guardar", "Guardar como...", etc. Para simplificar el problema solo intenté colocar el comando "Guardar" cuando el usuario realice las operaciones de las pestañas "sumar" y/o restar.

Al implementar el método `event_generate` en los módulos `sumar_app.py` y `restar_app.py` y pasarlos, posteriormente a la clase `MenuApp` del módulo `menu_app.py` se deberían ejecutar los eventos definidos por cada uno, lo cual no sucede.

Esta pregunta está íntimamente relacionada con una que realicé anteriormente:

- [¿Cómo estructurar una GUI (tkinter) para que tenga en archivos separados la App principal y los componentes secundarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355864/c%C3%B3mo-estructurar-una-gui-tkinter-para-que-tenga-en-archivos-separados-la-app)

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo para que pongas el bloque `try..except` dentro del bucle `while True`?

Comment: Ahora que lo analizo, me doy cuenta que no es necesario colocarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que enlazas el evento a una instancia que no es, recuerda siempre que `widget.bind` enlaza a un widget concreto, a una instancia de la clase concreta. En `memu_app.py`:

- La línea   `comandos_sumar = sumapp.SumarApp(self)` genera una nueva instancia del widget `suma_pp.SumarApp`, instancia que nunca llegas a mostrar y que nunca usas realmente. Es un objeto completamente distinto del generado en `app.App` con:

  ```
    self.sumar_pestaña = sumapp.SumarApp(self.__nb)
  ```
- Con `comandos_sumar.bind('<<GuardarResultado>>', self.guardar_resultado_suma)` enlazas correctamente el evento, pero a esa instancia no a la que realmente el usuario ve y la que lanza luego el evento, la creada en `app.App`.

La  solución más simple es realizar el enlace en `app.App` sobre la instancia correcta:

**`app.py`**

```
class App:

    def crear_tab_sumar(self, event):
        self.sumar_pestaña = sumapp.SumarApp(self.__nb)
        self.sumar_pestaña.bind(   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            '<<GuardarResultado>>', self.__menu.guardar_resultado_suma)
            )
        self.__nb.add(self.sumar_pestaña, text='SUMAR')
        self.__nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.__nb.select(self.sumar_pestaña)

    def crear_tab_restar(self, event):
        self.restar_pestaña = restapp.RestarApp(self.__nb)
        self.restar_pestaña.bind(  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            '<<GuardarResultado>>', self.__menu.guardar_resultado_resta
            )
        self.__nb.add(self.restar_pestaña, text='RESTAR')
        self.__nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.__nb.select(self.restar_pestaña)
```

Otra opción más "bizarra" es generar una tagbind personalizada en los dos Frames de `RestarApp` y `SumarApp` y luego realizar un enlace a la clase desde dónde quieras:

**`sumar_app.py`**

```
class SumarApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        index = bindtags.index("Frame")
        bindtags.insert(index, "FSumar")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
```

**`restar_app.py`**

```
class RestarApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        index = bindtags.index("Frame")
        bindtags.insert(index, "FRestar")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
```

**`menu_app.py`**

```
class MenuApp(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        parent.bind_class(
            "FSumar", '<<GuardarResultado>>', self.guardar_resultado_suma
            )
        parent.bind_class(
            "FRestar", '<<GuardarResultado>>', self.guardar_resultado_resta
            )
```

---

Ten en cuenta que el menú se duplicará cada vez que el evento se produzca, para que ésto solo ocurra una vez bastaría por ejemplo con un condicional en la callback que crea el submenú para que compruebe si ya existe.

Ten cuidado con los ciclos `while` o cualquier código mínimamente bloqueante en una GUI con el mainloop en ejecución, si se bloquea el mainloop la interfaz dejará de responder a eventos y se congelará. Cualquier ciclo se debe sustituir por el uso de `after` si la iteración en si no es bloqueante o directamente pasar el ciclo completo a un hilo o subproceso si cada iteración puede tardar también en ejecutarse.

En tu caso, realmente el ciclo es innecesario dado que itera una sola vez, la forma correcta sería simplemente:

**`sumar_app.py`**

```
class SumarApp(tk.Frame):

    def sumar(self):
        '''
        Este método intenterá realizar la suma algebraíca entre los dos (2) valores 
        ingresados en el inicializador de la clase.
        '''
        try:
            self.__resultado.set(self.__valor_1.get() + self.__valor_2.get())
        except (tk.TclError, ValueError):
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Has colocado mal un valor.')
        else:
            tk.Entry(
                self, textvariable=self.__resultado, state='readonly'
                ).grid(row=4, column=0)
            self.event_generate('<<GuardarResultado>>')
```

similar para `restar_app.py`.

Comment: Pensando un poco, no me gusta mucho el cambio de menús mediante eventos. Como bien dices, se puede duplicar el item añadido, además de no saber luego qué variable es la que habría que guardar. Una solución mejor sería hacer un menú dinámico en función de la pestaña que se visualiza. Si tengo tiempo lo añadiré como respuesta.